# OnItemLongClickListener not called on ListView with BaseAdapter implementation

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, android-actionmode

I have an `Activity` extending `BaseActivity`. It contains a `ListView` which gets initialized by my Adapter (extending `BaseAdapter`). Each item in the list view is a `CardView` with a `Button`, `TextView` & `ProgressBar`. One of the `TextView` and `ProgressBar` are dynamic so I have created a `Runnable` Countdown task which updates the TextView and the ProgressBar. The Countdown task is called every 100 milliseconds using `android.os.Handler.postDelayed()`.

The problem is that I want to implement `OnItemLongClickListener` for each item in the `ListView` to show action bar using `ActionMode.Callback` implementation for operations like Delete, Edit etc. I have implemented the `OnItemLongClickListener` but it never gets invoked. One weird thing I could see is that when I change my Countdown task delay to **3000 milliseconds**, it works as expected.

**Here is my basic implementation:**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_accounts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"></ListView>
```

`CardView` (each item of the list):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card_view"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/applicationName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/CustomBlack"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="miniorange"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_acc_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/CustomBlack"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            />


    </FrameLayout>



    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/token_num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:textColor="@color/CustomBlack"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            />


         <Button

            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:text="SCAN QR"
            android:background="@color/ButtonNavyBlue"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/qrcode_scan_white"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="130dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>


        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dip"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
            />


    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**My ListActivity:**

```
public class ListAccountsActivity extends BaseActivity {

private ListView mUserList;
private List<Users> mUsers;
private UserAccountsListAdapter mUserAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mUserList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_accounts);

    // Initialize Users list from Database
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    mUserAdapter = new UserAccountsListAdapter(ListAccountsActivity.this, mUsers, new
            BtnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBtnClick() {
            // My onclick action here
        }
    });

    mUserList.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
    mUserList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                       View view, int position, long id) {
            onListItemSelect(position);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    startCountdown();
}

private void startCountdown() {
    if (mUserList != null) {
        countdownTask = new CountdownTask(ListAccountsActivity.this, new CountdownTask
                .Listener() {
            @Override
            public void updateTextAndProgress() {
                updateTextAndProgressView();
            }
        });
        countdownTask.run();
    }
}

private void updateTextAndProgressView() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mUserList.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = mUserList.getChildAt(i);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.token_num);           

        // Update this TextView and ProgressBar
    }
}

private void onListItemSelect(int position) {
    mUserAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
    boolean hasCheckedItems = mUserAdapter.getSelectedCount() > 0;

    if (hasCheckedItems && mActionMode == null)
        // there are some selected items, start the actionMode
        mActionMode = startActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());
    else if (!hasCheckedItems && mActionMode != null)
        // there no selected items, finish the actionMode
        mActionMode.finish();

    if (mActionMode != null)
        mActionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(mUserAdapter
                .getSelectedCount()) + " selected");
}

private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete:

                SparseBooleanArray selected = mUserAdapter
                        .getSelectedIds();
                for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                        Users selectedItem = (Users) mUserAdapter
                                .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                        mUserAdapter.remove(selectedItem);
                    }
                }
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mUserAdapter.removeSelection();
        mActionMode = null;
    }
}
}
```

**CountdownTask:**

```
public class CountdownTask implements Runnable {

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Context context;
private Listener listner;

public CountdownTask(Context context, Listener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listner = listener;
}

interface Listener {
    void updateTextAndProgress();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    listner.updateTextAndProgress();
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
}
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class UserAccountsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<Users> accountList;
private BtnClickListener btnClickListener;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public UserAccountsListAdapter(Context context, List<Users> accountList, BtnClickListener btnClickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.accountList = accountList;
    this.btnClickListener = btnClickListener;
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return accountList.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return accountList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_account_layout2, null);
        convertView.setLongClickable(true);
    }

    Button button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClickListener.onBtnClick();
        }
    });

    TextView accountEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_acc_email);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    accountEmail.setText(accountList.get(position).getUserKey());

    return convertView;
}

public int getSelectedCount() {
return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}

public void remove(UserAccountItem object) {
    accountList.remove(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}
public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to your `Listview` Row Items layout--inside `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

problem is your `Listview` has focusable elements `Button` which blocks the list item click event.

Answer (score 0):

Add in ListView

```
android:longClickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Update your `ListView` XML with below code

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_accounts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"></ListView>
```

**Update Custom View too**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/applicationName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="miniorange"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/CustomBlack"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_acc_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35sp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:textColor="@color/CustomBlack"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />


            </FrameLayout>


            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/token_num"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:textColor="@color/CustomBlack"
                    android:textSize="50dp" />


                <Button

                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="130dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                    android:background="@color/ButtonNavyBlue"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/qrcode_scan_white"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:text="SCAN QR"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />


                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="4dip"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar" />


            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: update your custom view too and if still it not works then debug your onItemLongClick, because i think everything is right in implementation.